# Laptop shuts off after 10 minutes while power plug in without battery

Tags: power-supply

Laptop is getting shut down after 10 minutes while its run by power (plugged in )without battery, but with battery as well as plugged in it runs first 10 minutes by power then automatically runs by battery until the battery runs out and the laptop is not also charging after 10 minutes. I can charge the battery in full while the laptop is shut downed, but the battery not been charged while the Laptop is on/during its working time. The laptop can be run (2 hrs )with full charge battery but without battery only 10 minutes then it shuts itself . The laptop is not overheating all the ventilations are cleared, there is not any faults with power cable / connection as the power indicator light keeps on when plug in.

Any body who  knows the solution of this problem will be highly appreciated .

HP Pavilion dv6.  i7 4GB RAM Windows 7 home OS about 2 years old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd had a similar problem in the past with my old laptop. When I got it checked out, I was told that the circuitry had probably been badly affected by the fluctuations in the voltage while it was plugged in. It cost me a pretty penny to get it fixed as well.

It's almost certainly a hardware problem and not a software or OS issue. You'll need to get it checked out on-site.